# Why does an old R package ask for a recent dependecy

Tags: r, package, plotly, version, purrr

I am facing a problem in the installation and calling of plotly (and highcharter), the package asks for the version 1.0.1 of purrr to work but:

- There is no precision about the version of purrr in the description
- I need to have purr in an older version (about 0.3.3 - 0.3.5)

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
  namespace 'purrr' 0.3.3 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.1 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'plotly'
```

I tried to install an old version of plotly (4.9.1 released in 2019) but it asks for the version 1.0.1 of purrr (released in 2023)

I also tried to install first plotly with the good version of purrr (1.0.1) and then install the older version of purrr but the error don't change:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'plotly' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace 'purrr' 0.3.3 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.1 is required
```

I don't have any idea why this problem happen do you have any idea?

Comment: *"There is no precision about the version of purrr in the description"*: while `plotly` just lists `purrr` (no version), plotly also includes `tidyr` which 4 months ago switched from `purrr` to `purrr (>= 1.0.0)`; I don't know what version of `tidyr` you have, but if _that_ has seen any recent updates, then that might make sense. Even if `tidyr` is not the culprit here, the bottom line is that the dependency _tree_ drives the minimum version of a package, not just the package itself. Check all of the subordinate packages for more insight.

Comment: As for the `already loaded` error, you will need to close R completely (all local sessions), then start up without a project loaded (at least, one that does not directly or indirectly use purrr). After that, then `install.packages("purrr")` should work. This problem is because the shared libraries (`.dll`, `.so`, `.library`, whichever for your OS) cannot be overwritten by R, so installation fails. (It would be nice to finally get a fix for _this_ issue, but it's the "norm" in R.)